# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'e' was corrupted. occurred

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2010

```
    #include<iostream> 
    #include <list> 
    using namespace std;

class Euler {
private:
    int korifes = 0;
    int akmes = 0;
    int* pinakas[];
public:
    void print() { cout << *pinakas[0]; return; }

    Euler(int korifess, int akmess);
    ~Euler() { delete[] *pinakas; }

    void addAkmes(int kor1, int kor2);
};

Euler::Euler(int korifess, int akmess) : akmes(akmess), korifes(korifess) {
    *pinakas = new int(korifes);
    *pinakas[0] = 89;
}

int main() {
    Euler e(2, 1);
    e.print();
}
```

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'e' was corrupted. occurred...i can not find where i am wrong in my code.

Comment: There's some confusion in your code about what you want `pinakas` to be, and how you use it. Can you clarify: is it supposed to be an array of `int`, or an array of pointers? With that clarification, I could then (maybe) identify and correct the other errors in your code.

Comment: it is an array of int and size 'korifes'...the number 89 is just a test number and the number 'akmes' is irerevant at this point of the code

Comment: `pinakas` has no size so therefore has no space allocated to it, writing to it is undefined behaviour (in fact having unsized arrays in structures is not valid c++)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of errors in your code, all related to the nature of the `pinakas` member variable. As it stands, you are declaring this as an array of pointers (to `int`), and, furthermore, you are using a non-standard syntax for 'flexible' arrays (the empty `[]`).

I don't normally just paste 'fixed' code as an answer but, in this case, that code (with the added `\\\` comments where I've made changes) is likely to be the most succinct way to help you.

*Although, as many here will no doubt point out, it is **far better** to avoid the use of 'raw' pointers and the `new` and `delete` operators, and use the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container, instead.*

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <list> 
//using namespace std;/// This is considered 'bad practice' by many programmers
using std::cout;/// Just use the aspect of the STL that you need!

class Euler {
private:
    int korifes = 0;
    int akmes = 0;
    int* pinakas;/// This will point an 'array' of integers
public:
    void print() {
        cout << pinakas[0]; return;/// No longer any need for the dereference (*)
    }
    Euler(int korifess, int akmess);
    ~Euler() {
        delete[] pinakas;/// No need for the dereference (*)
    }
//  void addAkmes(int kor1, int kor2);/// You haven't provided an actual definition for this, but your never use it!
};

Euler::Euler(int korifess, int akmess) : akmes(akmess), korifes(korifess)/// NOTE: Members are initialized in DECLARATION order!
{
    pinakas = new int[korifes];/// Use "[]" (not "()") to allocate an array!
    pinakas[0] = 89;/// No need for the dereference (*)
}
```

Feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: at the 'delete [ ] pinakas' are the [ ] needed?since pinakas is not a array

Comment: @Angel The simple rule is that if you use the `new` operator with `[]` (as here), then the corresponding `delete` operator must also have the `[]` (also, as here).